# Chaining array methods (filter, map, reduce) instead of using double loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, reduce

I encountered a problem that I just can't wrap my head around...
so here is what I am trying to do.

Given the following array of objects,

```
products = [
    { name: 'Sonoma', ingredients: ['artichoke', 'sundried tomatoes', 'mushrooms'], containsNuts: false },
    { name: 'Pizza Primavera', ingredients: ['roma', 'sundried tomatoes', 'goats cheese', 'rosemary'], containsNuts: false },
    { name: 'South Of The Border', ingredients: ['black beans', 'jalapenos', 'mushrooms'], containsNuts: false },
    { name: 'Blue Moon', ingredients: ['blue cheese', 'garlic', 'walnuts'], containsNuts: true },
    { name: 'Taste Of Athens', ingredients: ['spinach', 'kalamata olives', 'sesame seeds'], containsNuts: true },
];
```

I know I could run this through nested loop to add the keys by ingredient name, then increment the value as I loop through the count like below :

```
      let ingredientCount = {}; 

  for (i = 0; i < products.length; i += 1) {
    for (j = 0; j < products[i].ingredients.length; j += 1) { //loop ingredients 
      ingredientCount[products[i].ingredients[j]] = (ingredientCount[products[i].ingredients[j]] || 0) + 1; 
    }
  }
```

As a result, ingredientCount should be something like: { "artichoke": 1 "mushrooms": 2 } ***

The issue here is that I need to use map and reduce to create the results that is the same as above.

```html
let ingredientCount = {}

    ingredientCount = 
    products.filter ((value) => {
        // filter out arrays within ingredients 
        // so out come should be like  
        /* 
        [ingredients: ['artichoke', 'sundried tomatoes', 'mushrooms']
        ,ingredients: ['roma', 'sundried tomatoes', 'goats cheese', 'rosemary']
        ,ingredients: ['black beans', 'jalapenos', 'mushrooms']
        ,ingredients: ['blue cheese', 'garlic', 'walnuts']
        ,ingredients: ['spinach', 'kalamata olives', 'sesame seeds']
        */

    }).map ((value) => {
        /* then take out ingredients and map this array to  
        arthichoke: ['artichoke','artichoke','artichoke']
        sundried tomatoes: ['sundried tomatoes']
        etc... 
        */

    
    }).reduce((acc, value) => {
        /* then reduce arrays within each key to numbers. 
        hence, the output should be 

        artichokes: artichokes.length (i.e. 3 )
        sundried toamatoes: 1
        
        */
    })
```

Would there be anyway that I can use above array methods for the exact same result without having to use loop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thinks that the loops are fine. But you want to use only array methods. Please can you explain the filter part, because i do not get it

Comment: I do not think that this kind of concatenations give a  better solution to the problem, because two main reasons, first it obfuscate the code, second the performance are worst. By the other hand the loop example is more readable and faster

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `map()`, `flat()` and then `reduce()`. The function `flat()` flattens the array.

```js
products = [
    { name: 'Sonoma', ingredients: ['artichoke', 'sundried tomatoes', 'mushrooms'], containsNuts: false },
    { name: 'Pizza Primavera', ingredients: ['roma', 'sundried tomatoes', 'goats cheese', 'rosemary'], containsNuts: false },
    { name: 'South Of The Border', ingredients: ['black beans', 'jalapenos', 'mushrooms'], containsNuts: false },
    { name: 'Blue Moon', ingredients: ['blue cheese', 'garlic', 'walnuts'], containsNuts: true },
    { name: 'Taste Of Athens', ingredients: ['spinach', 'kalamata olives', 'sesame seeds'], containsNuts: true },
];

let obj = products
              .map(p => p.ingredients)
              .flat()
              .reduce((obj, val) => {
                  obj[val] = (obj[val] || 0) + 1;
                  return obj;
              }, {});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `forEach` or `map`, and maintain a final array that only needs to be updated.

```js
let products = [
    { name: 'Sonoma', ingredients: ['artichoke', 'sundried tomatoes', 'mushrooms'], containsNuts: false },
    { name: 'Pizza Primavera', ingredients: ['roma', 'sundried tomatoes', 'goats cheese', 'rosemary'], containsNuts: false },
    { name: 'South Of The Border', ingredients: ['black beans', 'jalapenos', 'mushrooms'], containsNuts: false },
    { name: 'Blue Moon', ingredients: ['blue cheese', 'garlic', 'walnuts'], containsNuts: true },
    { name: 'Taste Of Athens', ingredients: ['spinach', 'kalamata olives', 'sesame seeds'], containsNuts: true },
];

let iCount = {};
products.forEach((c) => c.ingredients.forEach((i) => iCount.hasOwnProperty(i) ? iCount[i]++ : iCount[i] = 1));
console.log(iCount);
```

Comment: You are using `map()` like it is `forEach()`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using .reduce method and .forEach method of an array.

```js
var products = [
    { name: 'Sonoma', ingredients: ['artichoke', 'sundried tomatoes', 'mushrooms'], containsNuts: false },
    { name: 'Pizza Primavera', ingredients: ['roma', 'sundried tomatoes', 'goats cheese', 'rosemary'], containsNuts: false },
    { name: 'South Of The Border', ingredients: ['black beans', 'jalapenos', 'mushrooms'], containsNuts: false },
    { name: 'Blue Moon', ingredients: ['blue cheese', 'garlic', 'walnuts'], containsNuts: true },
    { name: 'Taste Of Athens', ingredients: ['spinach', 'kalamata olives', 'sesame seeds'], containsNuts: true },
];

var result = products.reduce((acc,obj) => 
   {obj.ingredients.forEach(ob=> acc[ob] = acc[ob]+1 || 1)
    return acc;
},{});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to reduce the array and increment the count as you go.

```js
const products = [{
    name: 'Sonoma',
    ingredients: ['artichoke', 'sundried tomatoes', 'mushrooms'],
    containsNuts: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Pizza Primavera',
    ingredients: ['roma', 'sundried tomatoes', 'goats cheese', 'rosemary'],
    containsNuts: false
  },
  {
    name: 'South Of The Border',
    ingredients: ['black beans', 'jalapenos', 'mushrooms'],
    containsNuts: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Blue Moon',
    ingredients: ['blue cheese', 'garlic', 'walnuts'],
    containsNuts: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Taste Of Athens',
    ingredients: ['spinach', 'kalamata olives', 'sesame seeds'],
    containsNuts: true
  },
];

const result = products.reduce((acc, { ingredients }) => {
  ingredients.forEach((ingredient) => {
    acc[ingredient] = (acc[ingredient] || 0) + 1;
  });
  return acc;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flatMap` and `reduce`. (In addition with `??` and `,` operators)

```js
const products = [
    { name: 'Sonoma', ingredients: ['artichoke', 'sundried tomatoes', 'mushrooms'], containsNuts: false },
    { name: 'Pizza Primavera', ingredients: ['roma', 'sundried tomatoes', 'goats cheese', 'rosemary'], containsNuts: false },
    { name: 'South Of The Border', ingredients: ['black beans', 'jalapenos', 'mushrooms'], containsNuts: false },
    { name: 'Blue Moon', ingredients: ['blue cheese', 'garlic', 'walnuts'], containsNuts: true },
    { name: 'Taste Of Athens', ingredients: ['spinach', 'kalamata olives', 'sesame seeds'], containsNuts: true },
];

const ingredientCount = products
  .flatMap(({ ingredients }) => ingredients)
  .reduce((acc, item) => ((acc[item] = (acc[item] ?? 0) + 1), acc), {});

console.log(ingredientCount);
```